# Primefaces signature line drawn from pointer is not at the tip

Tags: primefaces

I am using the PF signature component (v12.0.0) as follows

```
<p:signature id="signature" value="#{assignmentViewV2.signature}" style="width:600px;height:150px" widgetVar="sig" required="true" guideline="true" guidelineOffset="15" requiredMessage="Signature is required" />
```

But when the signature is drawn, the line does not appear from the tip of the mouse pointer.  In the 1st screenshot I am guiding the mouse pointer tip along the guideline. In the 2nd screenshot I draw vertically.  It appears that the line is emanating from the right ear/barb shown circled. How can I get the line to be drawn from the tip of the mouse pointer?  I don't see any parameters in the tag to affect this. I don't see anything obvious in my CSS file that could be affecting the pointer.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it with this CSS:

```css
body .ui-inputfield.kbw-signature {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Reported: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9118

Fixed for 12.0.0-RC3: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/9119